# Opened file Highlighting in Linux Ubuntu console

Tags: console, filename

First(I am using linux in terminal, (console mode),(no graphical extension),
like on server.
The question is following:
Is it possible to install some kind of script, that highlights "opened file",
for example in green color(or any other), (only filename, nothing complex)?
Why? because that sometimes I and my collegues edit same files on server.
It is not very neccesary, but it is conveniet, You agree?
Of course text editor promts you about you are to save already edited file,.
Just in case,
And of course not heavy  script, because it just does what it does.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to see it (but often not useful for your objective, see later) is using the `fuser` command, from the `psmisc` package.

The command `fuser -a *` will work as a sort-of `ls`, and will print a process id if something is keeping a file open. For example:

```
⌂71% [romano:~/tmp] 1 % fuser -a *
/home/romano/tmp/example.log:
/home/romano/tmp/example.pdf:
/home/romano/tmp/example.tex:
```

then in another windows/terminal/virtual console/connection do a `cat >> example.tex` to keep the file open, and:

```
⌂71% [romano:~/tmp] 1 % fuser -a *
/home/romano/tmp/example.log:
/home/romano/tmp/example.pdf:
/home/romano/tmp/example.tex:  7742
```

`fuser` tells you that the process with PID 7742 is keeping the file open.

**Nevertheless**, a lot of editors do not keep the file open; they read it in memory (remember that unix-like OSs have virtual memory), and then close it. For example, opening the file `example.tex` with `vim` has no effect on `fuser` output.)

So the double-editing avoidance is left to the editor; `vim` or `emacs` use a lock file and warn you on opening it twice.

You can also see the comments and answers in this [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321930/check-if-file-is-open-with-lsof).

Comment: Thanks Rmano, one more question, is there any solution in Linux Ubuntu, like SVN??(version check...)

Comment: @ViktorsAls There are tens of solution of version control systems --- from the simple `CVS` to `git` or mercurial. Your problem seems in part similar to managing dotfiles; see for example https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dotfiles as a starting point.